# Unable to start Airflow Server - OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python-2.7, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I setup Airflow locally using the [Installation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/installation.html) and [Quickstart](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/start.html) pages.

I was able to originally get it up and running, and even follow the [Tutorial](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/tutorial.html).

Then when trying my own example which required the following

```
pip install 'apache-airflow[gcp,google_auth]'
```

When I try to run webserver with `airflow webserver -p 8080` I get the following error:

```
Running the Gunicorn Server with:
Workers: 4 sync
Host: 0.0.0.0:8080
Timeout: 120
Logfiles: - -
=================================================================
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 37, in <module>
    args.func(args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 75, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 996, in webserver
    gunicorn_master_proc = subprocess.Popen(run_args, close_fds=True)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 394, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1047, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get passed this, though not entirely sure of the root cause.

I reinstalled python with `brew reinstall python2` and notices there were some conflicts I had to force it to overwrite. Once I got passed this, `airflow webserver -p 8080` runs without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

On mac I tried `sudo pip install gunicorn` and it started working.